# How are AFTN costs charged to ANSP's and Airspace Users?

Tags: cost, air-traffic-management

I'd like to know how ANSP's like the FAA/SENEAM/etc.. get charged for sending and receiving messages over AFTN. I'm wondering if it is on a per characher/message basis or if they pay in bulk. Also, how do private Airspace Users or 3rd parties like Jeppesen pay. Since this network is actual copper and is so old, I'm wondering if SITA makes pure profit or if it is more complex than I understand.

Comment: The short answer is it's much more complex than you think. Communications between ANSPs and users is not always through AFTN.